# Using a query in ALTER TABLE in CREATE TRIGGER

Tags: mysql, alter-table

I'm trying to create a dynamic ALTER TABLE command but some of the command will be generated from a query. The problem is that I want to use this in a trigger!

Attempt 1:

```
ALTER TABLE `redinfomanager` CHANGE `Unterkategorie` `Unterkategorie` ENUM(("SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT('\'', REPLACE(`Unterkategorien`, '\r\n', '\',\''), '\'') SEPARATOR  ',') FROM `kategorien` GROUP BY '1'")) CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_swedish_ci NOT NULL;
```

Attempt 2:

```
SELECT @tmp:=GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT('\'', REPLACE(`Unterkategorien`, '\r\n', '\',\''), '\'') SEPARATOR  ',') FROM `kategorien` GROUP BY '1';
SET @query=CONCAT('ALTER TABLE `redinfomanager` CHANGE `Unterkategorie` `Unterkategorie` ENUM(', @tmp, ') CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_swedish_ci NOT NULL');
PREPARE stmt FROM @query;
EXECUTE stmt;
```

Attempt 3:

```
SET @kat = (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT('\'', REPLACE(`Unterkategorien`, '\r\n', '\',\''), '\'') SEPARATOR  ',') FROM kategorien GROUP BY '1');
PREPARE stmt FROM 'ALTER TABLE redinfomanager CHANGE Unterkategorie Unterkategorie ENUM(?) CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_swedish_ci NOT NULL';
EXECUTE stmt USING @kat;
```

It tells me:

> 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '; PREPARE stmt FROM 'ALTER TABLE `redinfomanager` CHANGE `Unterkategorie` `Unte' at line 1

How could I do that?

And what does that error stand for?

Comment: Running an `ALTER TABLE` command from a trigger is likely to be a *really* bad idea — `ALTER TABLE` locks the table, and will often end up having to rewrite the whole table, which may be a very slow operation if the table is large. If you have a column which does not have a well-defined set of possible values, don't use `ENUM()`. Use `VARCHAR` or similar instead.

Comment: Well, the table is not too big at all. The set is not very likely to change at all but right now I'm in the testing phase and so I don't have the time to edit all the changes by hand since I might change the set to see what happens.
But IS there a way to make this work???

Comment: Don't use an `ENUM`. An appropriately sized `VARCHAR` column will behave almost identically, and will allow you to use any string value without modifying the table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you're changing an `ENUM` value on a second table after every insert on the first table? Why not just make that a [foreign key constraint](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html). That will require whatever values you want to put in table 2 will have to have a value from table 1. It will be much more efficient, too:

Just an example ([sqlfiddle link](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/41bea)):

```
CREATE TABLE category (
  id INT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  description VARCHAR(50)
);

CREATE TABLE thing (
  id INT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  cat_id INTEGER,
  description VARCHAR(50),
  FOREIGN KEY (cat_id) REFERENCES category(id)
);

INSERT INTO category (description) 
VALUES 
   ('Category 1')
  ,('Category 2');

INSERT INTO thing (cat_id, description)
VALUES 
   (1, 'Thing 1')
  ,(1, 'Thing 2')
  ,(2, 'Thing 3');

INSERT INTO thing (cat_id, description)
VALUES
   (3, 'Imma Fail!')
```

If you run it, the third insert will fail, because there's not an `id` of 3 in the `category` table.

Comment: It looks like the sqlfiddle link isn't the same as what I have above... it probably doesn't save when you build a schema with an error (which is probably the better thing to do `:)`). But if you copy and paste the above, you get the following error when you try to build schema: `Schema Creation Failed: Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (``db_2_f1164``.``thing``, CONSTRAINT ``thing_ibfk_1`` FOREIGN KEY (``cat_id``) REFERENCES ``category`` (``id``)):`

Comment: Thank you! This does work!and also thank you for teaching me something completely new to me!